# Bash Extending hash table (dictionary)

Tags: bash, hash, dictionary

I try to fill my hash table with data from the file. With this code

```
      templates="./templates"
      declare -A ARRAY
      ARRAY+=([a]='b')
      ARRAY+=([d]='f')
      cat $templates | while read line 
      do
      a=`(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 1)`
      b=`(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2)`
      ARRAY+=([a]=b)
      done


      for x in ${!ARRAY[@]}
      do
      echo "$x - ${ARRAY["$x"]}"
      done
```

It gives me only

```
  a - b
  d - f
```

templates file is:

```
nazwisko: towar
Kowalski: ksiazki
Nowak: programy
```

Comment: What is the output you expected?

Comment: @DaveJarvis: I expected nazwisko - towar, kowalski - ksiazki etc. in an array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One problem with your code, and lots of simplification that can happen.

First, the problem:

This line:

```
ARRAY+=([a]=b)
```

Should be:

```
ARRAY+=(["$a"]="$b")
```

And for the simplification:

```
declare -A arr=([a]=b [d]=f)
while IFS=': ' read -r a b; do
    arr+=(["$a"]="$b")
done < "$templates"

for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    printf '%s - %s\n' "$i" "${arr[$i]}"
done
```